# stuck on Nginx location directives ending in jpg

Tags: nginx

I can serve my static file by Nginx as below:

```
/etc/nginx/site-available/mydomain.com

server {
  listen        80;
  server_name   mydomain.com *.mydomain.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:5005;
    .   .   .    //Some codes here     
  }
   
  location /images/{
    root  /var/www/; 
    expires  1000d;
  } 
}
```

The upper code works successfully and images load by nginx rather than my .Net core program, I have problem while replacing the `second` location block :

```
location ~* \.(jpg|png|webp)$  {
    alias  /var/www/images;            #try 1    :(
    alias  /var/www/images/;                #try 2   :(
    root  /var/www/images/;           #try 3    :(
    root  /var/www/images;                #try 4    :(
    expires  1000d;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to change the `root` from `root  /var/www/;`?

Comment: Thanks.  :) . It worked. I thought I had to change the root too. Thanks a lot